# Automatically save settings on exit C#

Tags: c#, settings

In VB.NET there is an option to "Automagically save settings on exit" is there an equivalent option in C# or does one need to write the following code?"

```
private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use ApplicationExit instead.

```
Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(Application_ApplicationExit);

void Application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Alternatively, you could also save on every change:

```
Settings.Default.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Default_PropertyChanged);

void Default_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Warning: If you use the second approach, please consider the comments by @Hans Passant

Comment: I think saving the properties on every change makes the user interactions a little awkward, especially if you allow them to cancel their interaction. Saving when the user closes a form, cancels, loads some subsystem provides a better overall experience.

Comment: Thank u for your help... PS: Inclined to agree with Ritch but I do like applicationExit better.

Comment: PropertyChanged is dangerous.  If the program subsequently dies, it may well die again at startup because of the saved setting.  You user can never get it started again, the file is very hard to find.

Comment: @Hans - That's an interesting point. I'm going to add that to my list of criticisms.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, too. If you're using Windows Forms, bring up the Events tab from within the Properties Pane in Design-View for the Form you'd like to use, and scroll down till you see the Closing Event, then double-click it.

Next, just add the code shown below.

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, that's it. I prefer to handle save, reset, reload at the form level because the settings are shared across the app. Calling .Reset() on FormCancel does the right thing for the user, as well as calling .Save() when the form closes. If the app crashes after that point, the settings are preserved. I think that saving on AppStart/Exit doesn't do the right thing for the user at the right time.

```
Settings.Default.Save();
```

Other interesting methods:

```
.Upgrade();

.Reset();

.Reload();
```

Answer (score -2):

according to this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) it's exactly the same

Comment: ...except it doesn't. The original question asked how to automatically save settings on exit.